# Other way to use <br> in Jquery with dynamic element without causing blank line when remove and add specific elements. (Solved by me)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have repeatedly test code to find a problem and found it and the solution but that part of the error is needed so it wont be ugly such as button be right next to each other or below each other, so I use `<br>` to separate them but it seems that when I remove that element, it does not remove the `<br>` part.

I solve it by adding a class to `<br class='br'>` and then $(".br").remove();

Just gonna leave it here for anyone to either correct me or offer a better way to do this or use this as a solution to theirs.

https://jsfiddle.net/Necrorifter/k0yvsbj9/64/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="placeholder_choice"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

```
function startGame() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Intro();
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".OnOff", function() {
    var button = $(this).val();
    if (button == "Next") {
      Conclusion();
    } else if (button == "Back") {
      Intro();
    }
  });

  function Intro() {
    $("#Intro").remove();
    $("#Conclusion").remove();
    $(".OnOff").remove();
    $(".br").remove();
    $("<div id='Intro'>" + "<p>Hello, welcome to my game!</p>" + "</div>").insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(0);
    $("<button class='OnOff' value='Next'>Okay (Next)</button>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice");
  }

  function Conclusion() {
    $("#Intro").remove();
    $("#Conclusion").remove();
    $(".OnOff").remove();
    $(".br").remove();
    $("<p id='Conclusion'>Yay, i like this boring ass test! Let do it again!</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");
    $("<button class='OnOff' value='Back'>Okay (Back)</button>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice");
    $("<br class='br'><br class='br'><button class='OnOff' value='Middle'>Empty (Middle)</button>").insertBefore("#placeholder_choice");
  }
}
startGame();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by adding a class to `<br class='br'>` and then $(".br").remove();